# Oracle: function based index selective uniqueness

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have to maintain history and so I am using is_deleted column which can have 'Y' or 'N'. But for any instance of is_deleted 'N' I should have uniwue entry for (a,b,c) composite columns.

When I am tryin to create function based unique index I am getting error.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fn_unique_idx ON table1  (CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' then (id, name, type) end);
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You would need something like

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fn_unique_idx 
    ON table1 (CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' THEN id ELSE null END,
               CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' THEN name ELSE null END,
               CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' THEN type ELSE null END);
```

An example of the constraint in action

```
SQL> create table table1 (
  2    id number,
  3    name varchar2(10),
  4    type varchar2(10),
  5    is_deleted varchar2(1)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fn_unique_idx
  2      ON table1 (CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' THEN id ELSE null END,
  3                 CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' THEN name ELSE null END,
  4                 CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' THEN type ELSE null END);

Index created.

SQL> insert into table1 values( 1, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'N' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values( 1, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Y' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values( 1, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Y' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values( 1, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'N' );
insert into table1 values( 1, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'N' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.FN_UNIQUE_IDX) violated


SQL> insert into table1 values( 1, 'Foo', 'Zee', 'N' );

1 row created.
```

Comment: But my usecase is when is_deleted = 'N' then combination of (id,name,type) - composite key should be unique. Will your query achieve the same?

Comment: @Andriod_enthusiast - It certainly appears to.  I updated my answer with the test I ran.

Comment: thanks much. appreciate it. So if I have not null consraint on these columns I think I can omit ELSE null

Comment: No, you need to map the data in the rows where is_deleted is 'Y' to NULL in order to exclude them from the index.  You need the ELSE condition

Comment: umm.. but when I created without Else null it works as well. I didn;t quite get your previous comment. Can you plz elaborate. thanks

Comment: Actually, the ELSE part is redundant. If there is no ELSE part, CASE returns NULL by default. It is just good practice to spell it out, it has nothing to do with having NOT NULL constraints on individual columns.

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fn_unique_idx ON table1  
    (CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' then (id||','|| name||','|| type) end);
```

Comment: While lacking the clear explanation of Justin Cave's this approach also works and is a bit more concise in my opinion