# Conditional Unique Constraint, Ignored for Same Foreign Key

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, unique-constraint

I have a situation where I need to maintain a unique constraint for two columns  (FK_1, NAME) conditionally. The constraint should not apply for rows where a second foreign key is the same (FK_2).

```
ID    FK_1     FK_2    NAME
1     2        3       'X01'
2     2        3       'X01-A'
3     2        3       'X01'  --Accepted
4     2        4       'X01'  --Violation
5     3        5       'X01'  --Accepted
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that rows 1, 2, and 3 are valid, because FK_2 is the same. They break the unique constraint, but the unique constraint is ignored because FK_2 is the same. Row 4 will violate the unique constraint for (FK_1,NAME) because FK_2 would have been new. And finally, row 5 is fine due to the normal function of a unique constraint on (FK_1,NAME).

It's trying to determine how to handle row 3 that is the complication.

I've seen several examples of how to address this same problem when the equivalent of FK_2 is hard-coded to some extent ([Oracle: function based index selective uniqueness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702367/oracle-function-based-index-selective-uniqueness)), but I'm not sure how I can address this for a foreign key, where I really don't have control over the value of FK_2.

I have tried implementing a function-based unique index, but it results in a ORA-04091 exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNQ_TEST_FUNCTION(var_fk_1 IN NUMBER, var_fk_2 IN NUMBER, var_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
    result          NUMBER;
BEGIN
    result := null;
    IF (var_fk_1 IS NULL OR var_fk_2 IS NULL OR var_name IS NULL ) THEN
        result := null;
    ELSE
        SELECT COUNT(ID) INTO result FROM TEST1 WHERE
            FK_2 != var_fk_2 AND FK_1 = var_fk_1 AND NAME = var_name;
        IF (result <= 0) THEN
            result := null;
        ELSE
            result := 1;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN result;
END;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNQ_TEST ON TEST1 
    (
        UNQ_TEST_FUNCTION("FK_1","FK_2","NAME")
    ) 
;

INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID, FK_1, FK_2, NAME)
    VALUES (1, 2, 3, 'X01');

ORA-04091: table TEST1 is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

The exception makes perfect sense, but being unable to query the table puts me at a loss about where to go.

Comment: There is something suspicious about your data model.  I feel like it is missing an entity of some sort.

Comment: Well, it's not my real data model. I only wanted to include what I felt was relevant. What part seems off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting problem. I would approach this in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE t123_fk(
  FK_1 int,
  FK_2 int,
  CONSTRAINT t123_fk_pk PRIMARY KEY(FK_1, FK_2),
  CONSTRAINT fk_2_is_new_constr_violated UNIQUE(FK_1)
);

CREATE TABLE t123(
  ID int,
  FK_1 int,
  FK_2 int,
  NAME varchar2(100),
  constraint t123_fk FOREIGN KEY(FK_1, FK_2) REFERENCES t123_fk
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER some_name 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON t123
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t123_fk( fk_1, fk_2 )
  SELECT :new.FK_1, :new.FK_2 FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT 1 FROM t123_fk
     WHERE fk_1 = :new.fk_1 AND fk_2 = :new.fk_2
  );
END;
/
```

Table `t123` is the main table containing our data. 
Table `t123_fk` and the trigger are auxiliary and they are used only to help us to force our constraint (btw, our constraint is named `fk_2_is_new_constr_violated` in the above code).

---

Here is a test - the fourth insert will be rejected by the database:

```
insert into t123( id, fk_1, fk_2, name) values(1,2,3,'X01');
insert into t123( id, fk_1, fk_2, name) values(2,2,3,'X01-A');
insert into t123( id, fk_1, fk_2, name) values(3,2,3,'X01');
insert into t123( id, fk_1, fk_2, name) values(4,2,4,'X01'); // this insert will be rejected
insert into t123( id, fk_1, fk_2, name) values(5,3,5,'X01');
```

Comment: That works! I believe I need to make some adjustments to ensure that I have triggers that delete items from t123_fk when the corresponding records are deleted from t123, but that's the exact baseline I needed. Thanks!